# Unix will background running process stopped after disconnect the session

Tags: unix, bash

Say if I run some command in background:

```
./my_script.sh > /dev/null &
```

and I close putty immediately (which is equivalent to disconnect current session right?).

Will the background process finish? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you exit an interactive bash login shell, it sends a SIGHUP to all children unless the shell option `huponexit` is set to off.

When most userland processes receive a SIGHUP, they will exit.

You can also prefix the command with `nohup` to make it ignore the SIGHUP.  Moreover, you can `disown` it using an internal bash function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want backgrounded tasks to persist, look into using screen

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen
- http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/

To create or reconnect to a screen session called 'myprocess' which will persist across sessions:

- screen -DR myprocess

To list all screens:

- screen -ls

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should. Apparently my answer was too short.

Comment: The running script is still part of the shell process, even when sent to the background.  Without specifying "nohup", the process will die w/ the shell on exit